Module not found: Package path ./webgpu is not exported from package I am getting this error when i try to import imgly background removal
Every time I import the imply background removal I get this error like
Module not found: Package path ./webgpu is not exported from package C:\Users\dhruv\node_modules\onnxruntime-web (see exports field in C:\Users\dhruv\node_modules\onnxruntime-web\package.json)

  5743 | import ndarray3 from "ndarray";
  5744 | import * as ort_cpu from "onnxruntime-web";
> 5745 | import * as ort_gpu from "onnxruntime-web/webgpu";
       | ^
  5746 |
  5747 | // src/capabilities.js
  5748 | var webgpu = async () => {

I tried reinstalling the packages still did not work.
